# Default size classes seem to only work for iPad (XCode 6)

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, size-classes

I am trying to wrap my head around the new size classes in iOS8 and XCode6. I am attempting to create a nib, without a storyboard, and do something really simple--center a UIView on the screen.

Starting with a nib in the default size: w:Regular h:Regular, I place a 200x200 UIView onto the parent view and center it, then add contraints to pin it. In my preview pane, the UIView only shows up on the iPad view.

I need for this view to show up on iPads in lanscape and iPhones in portrait. I suppose some day i will understand why Apple thinks this is so much easier, but at the moment I'm bewildered.

When I switch my design view to any of the iPhone supported modes, the UIView disappears.

Even when I unpin the UIView and move it around in the design view, it never shows up in the iPhone view. In other words, I've tried everything to get this view to appear on an iPhone and nothing works.

Here is my UIView and settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Obviously there is something I'm missing, but I'm getting really frustrated trying to figure it out. Can anyone offer a clue? Thanks!

Comment: do you get what i mean? @pheepster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you defined your view only for the size classes `Regular & Regular`. For them to show up on the iPhone you will have to configure the view also for the appropriate size classes, which in case of the iPhone is `Regular & Compact` where `(<height> & <width>)`.

**UPDATE**:
The views generally only show up in the size classes for which they are *configured*. You currently have `Regular & Regular` selected, this can be seen from your screenshot. This means you defined it *only* for the devices with size classes `Regular & Regular`, which is the iPad in both orientations.

[image]

You need to add the views also in the size class that you are targeting, which are the size classes of the iPhone.

[image]